# Is like case insensitive by default in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I implemented case insensitive Store search by name/street.

First I wrote:

```
@Query("select t from Store t where lower(t.name) like lower(concat('%', :query, '%')) or lower(t.street) like lower(concat('%', :query, '%'))")
Page<Store> findAll(@Param("query") String query, Pageable pageable);
```

Then I just tested the other version and it worked for me.

```
@Query("select t from Store t where t.name like %:query% or t.street like %:query%")
Page<Store> findAll(@Param("query") String query, Pageable pageable);
```

Does it mean that Like oparation is case insensitive by default in Spring Data JPA? I read the reference docs, but could not find approve there.

Comment: Let me guess.  Your database is MySQL, right?  I don't think Spring Data JPA is to blame here.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yep the db is MySQL. What is the reason? I do not use MySQL usually, so have no idea :)

Comment: [Read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem thank you, I had no idea about that. Please add as answer, I will accept.